# Angular2 with Pace-Progress library, Error: Buffer is not defined

Tags: angular, webpack, es6-class, pace

The Pace library (Pace-Progress is the name of it on NPM because Pace was already taken) is throwing this error when imported. I am using Angular2 and Webpack. The line of code throwing the error is

```
exports.isBuffer = Buffer.isBuffer;
```

I have a buffer library available from NPM was well, but why would Pace be expecting me to load another library in advance for it to work? What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: It isn't clear why client-side library may use `Buffer`, because it is a part of Node api. I would suggest to investigate why it is used in the bundle in the first place. But the most simple way to use it in bundle is to use [Webpack polyfills for that](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#node).

Comment: Thanks! I set the buffer option to true in webpack and the error went away.

Comment: If you submit an answer with this I will mark it correct, as the polyfill buffer option was ultimately what got it working

Comment: Sure, you're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Buffer` is a part of Node API and usually shouldn't be found in client side code.

Most simple way to use it in bundle is to use [Webpack polyfills](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#node).